# How to put version information in a multi platform program *nix and win32?

Tags: winapi, unix, wix, versioning

I want to know what is the standard way of doing it.

currently I'm thinking in add a series of defines in a header file and inlcudie that file in the main resource file win win32 to update the version resource in win32 and in *nix make some global functions to return this information.

and in windows make the msi install file also reflect the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a reasonable way to do it.  I don't think there IS a standard way of doing this; there aren't any real standards for version reporting that are cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Since we wanted to avoid the overhead of changing a "version.cpp" or equivalent every time we hit build -- and thereby taking the time to do at least one compile and link -- we modify the binary after the build.

If you're outputting to e.g. ELF or PE format executables, you can use some basic knowledge of ELF or PE and a linker map to figure out what to replace, otherwise you can scan through the binary looking for a set pattern (we use something like static const char VERSION[] = "[VERSIONBLOCK xxxxxxxxxxxxx]";) and replace a portion (e.g. the xxxx part above) with relevant info:

- build date and time
- build machine
- username
- output of e.g. svnversion

Note that this won't work very well if your binaries are signed or compressed before this step, but usually you can engineer your build process so the signing/compressing happens after this step.

I'm sure a variant of this could be extended to hit the Win32 PE version metadata as well as any embedded version string.